# How to run selected bash commands

Tags: bash, selection

I have a large bash script and I need to rerun certain lines of code. Normally I would comment out any line I don't want to run and then execute the file on the shell. But that is rather cumbersome. I'd much rather select the lines I want to execute and do something like `M-x execute-selected-lines-in-the-current-directory`. Is there something like that?

Comment: What does the substring `in-the-current-directory` in the assumed command name `execute-selected-lines-in-the-current-directory` mean? Could you elaborate please? Do you want to run the selected lines in a directory different from the `default-directory` of the current shell script file buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `sh-execute-region` which is bound to `C-M-x` in `sh-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>M-|</kbd> (`shell-command-on-region`) then `sh` to pipe the current region to Bash. It works because `bash` supports running program from STDIN, e.g.,

```
~ $ echo 'date' | sh
Mon Feb 25 21:54:51 CST 2019
```

<kbd>M-|</kbd> runs via a fresh shell every time, so I'm not sure if it can work in your case.